# evaluate expression within a data frame

Tags: r, if-statement

My data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("John","Paul","Bob"), Age=c("20","30_&_5","40"))

  Name    Age
1 John     20
2 Paul 30_&_5
3  Bob     40
```

In the 'Age' column, I sometimes have an operation to perform (see line 2, where '&' can be understood as '+'), in order to get:

```
  Name    Age
1 John     20
2 Paul     35
3  Bob     40
```

What I tried:

```
library(stringr)

ifelse(
    str_detect(df$Age, "[[:digit:]]+_[+]_[[:digit:]]+"),
    {
        df$Age <- as.character(df$Age)
        new_age <- unlist(strsplit(df$Age,"_"))
        as.numeric(new_age[1]) + as.numeric(new_age[3])
    },
    df$Age
)

[1] "20" NA   "40"

Warning message:
In ifelse(str_detect(df$Age, "[[:digit:]]+_[+]_[[:digit:]]+"), { :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

However, when I remove the first line the code works as expected.

EDIT:
My problem is not about performing the operation. This is just an example that reproduces the error message I get.

Comment: Then what do you want?

Comment: What are you asking then??

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `eval(parse(...))`, i.e.

```
df$Age[grepl('_&_', df$A, fixed = TRUE)] <- eval(parse(text = gsub('_&_', '+', df$A, fixed = TRUE)))

#  Name Age
#1 John  20
#2 Paul  35
#3  Bob  40
```

Comment: My example is probably not good. The problem is not about the operation itself. I changed my example in my post.

Comment: You should expand and give a few more examples. Are all the cases like this? `_&_`?

Comment: Yes, the elements in column 'Age' are either integers or expression with '&' (not '+'). But this is an example dataset. My problem is not about the operation. It is about the 'NAs introduced by coercion'.

Comment: ok then this can be easily fixed. Have a look now. Those NAs in your case occur when `str_detect` does not...detect... the pattern that you give it

Comment: My problem is not about the operation. It is about the 'NAs introduced by coercion'. This is only an example to reproduce the error I get.

Comment: Yes I realize that. That's why I gave you an alternative option that does not do that. As I said above, Those NAs in your case occur when str_detect does not...detect... the pattern that you give it

Answer (score 0):

An option without `eval(parse(...))` and based on `purrr` and `stringr` could be:

```
map_dbl(str_extract_all(df$Age, "([0-9]+)"), ~ sum(as.numeric(.)))

[1] 20 35 40
```

Answer (score -1):

For arithmetic operations, you don't need to use pattern recognition such as str_detect

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("John","Paul","Bob"), Age=c("20","30+5","20*2"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

newAge <- sapply(df$Age, function(a) {
  eval(parse(text = a))
})

df$newAge <- newAge
```